# Error while deploying artifacts from Jenkins to Jfrog artifactory server

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, bintray, jcenter

I am facing issues while deploying simple artifacts from Jenkins to Jfrog Artifactory server. The following are the details:

**Tool versions**

- Jenkins version- 2.107.3
- Apache maven version- 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
- Artifactory version- 6.12.2

**Error log**

```
[ERROR] org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed: 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:144)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:109)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:116)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClient.<init>(PreemptiveHttpClient.java:72)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getHttpClient(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:145)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getHttpClient(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:140)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.executeGetRequest(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.getVersion(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:154)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Input sample, expected output and what did you try? You just exposed the error you are getting

Comment: David- I am trying to create a jenkin freestyle job which build and deploy artifacts for maven project to jfrog artifactory server. Rest of the details mentioned above like mvn, jenkins, jfrog artifactory versions.

Comment: @vaibhav Welcome to the community! It helps members to reproduce the problem and respond faster if you include more details about your job/plugin configurations and the code sample. You may please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help on asking good questions.

Comment: thanks Dibakar for the right post!!

Comment: Can you elaborate the actions you performing, the commands you are using. Also make sure your Artifactory server is reachable from your Jenkins server. You can test it with simple telnet command.

Comment: Shreedhar- i am able to telnet both machine as both are in same N/W segment.Steps i had performed -
1.create a freestyle job and give the SVN path in SCM.
2.select Maven3-Artifactory Integration in Build Environment and provide deatils of artifactory server.
3.In Build part, give the deatil of Maven Version and goals.
4.save and execute the build.
This is simple job for checking if artifacts are deploying on artifactory server.

Comment: Try upgrading your Jenkins plugins. The issue may be caused by conflicting versions of the Apache Http Client,  exposed by different plugins.

Comment: @EyalBenMoshe. My Artifactory plugin version is 3.4.0. need to update it to latest 3.4.1?

Comment: I suggest upgrading all plugins, not just the Artifactory plugin, but first, markup everything, so that you're able to rollback if something else stops working.